# want to use same table prefix in wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, wpmu

I am creating a news website. I have created sub-domain based wordpress multisite installation. But matter is, I want to fetch articles from my subdomain to main website (that are adjacent into my wordpress multisite network). My idea is:

**1)** suppose here is my main website mywebsite.com, I have subdomain based network like blog.mywebsite.com,sports.mywebsite.com,tech.mywebsite.com etc.

**2)** I want to show articles from subdomain to my main website (http://sports.mywebsite.com -> http://mywebsite.com). I am using same theme for all network.

Thanks,

Comment: ... and your question is??

Comment: I want to show articles from subdomain to my main website (http://sports.mywebsite.com -> http://mywebsite.com). I am using same theme for all network.